# Remove duplicates from array but ignoring one parameter with JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I get the unique array but ignoring one of the parameters in the array? I want to ignore the `name` and compare others, let's say...

```
let inventories = [
  {name: 'Polo Shirt', size: 'XL', price: 19.90, color: 'black'},
  {name: 'Polo Shirt (Stripe)', size: 'XL', price: 19.90, color: 'black'},
  {name: 'Polo Shirt (Printed)', size: 'XL', price: 19.90, color: 'black'},
  {name: 'Short Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 14.90, color: 'blue'},
  {name: 'Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 20.90, color: 'black'},
  {name: 'Long Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 14.90, color: 'blue'},
  {name: 'Long Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 14.90, color: 'blue'},
  {name: 'Long Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 14.90, color: 'blue'},
];
```

Result I want:

```
[
  {name: 'Polo Shirt (Printed)', size: 'XL', price: 19.90, color: 'black'},
  {name: 'Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 20.90, color: 'black'},
  {name: 'Long Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 14.90, color: 'blue'},
];
```

I know we can get unique array by:

```
inventories = inventories
  .map(JSON.stringify)
  .reverse()
  .filter(function(item, index, inventories) {
    return inventories.indexOf(item, index + 1) === -1;
```

But I'm not sure how to tell them to ignore `name` parameter...

Comment: Why choosing `Sleeve Polo Shirt` and not `Short Sleeve Polo Shirt`?!!

Comment: Which property we must check for duplicate?!!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki it doesn't matter choose which name, the goal for me here is to ignore the `name` parameter and find the unique arrays.

Properties that I wanna check is all others properties except `name` property

Answer (score 3):

I think, this is the most simplest ans. You can create a hashtable and generate a unique key based on properties other than `name`. See the following code:

```js
let inventories = [
  {name: 'Polo Shirt', size: 'XL', price: 19.90, color: 'black'},
  {name: 'Polo Shirt (Stripe)', size: 'XL', price: 19.90, color: 'black'},
  {name: 'Polo Shirt (Printed)', size: 'XL', price: 19.90, color: 'black'},
  {name: 'Short Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 14.90, color: 'blue'},
  {name: 'Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 20.90, color: 'black'},
  {name: 'Long Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 14.90, color: 'blue'},
  {name: 'Long Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 14.90, color: 'blue'},
  {name: 'Long Sleeve Polo Shirt', size: 'L', price: 14.90, color: 'blue'}
]

const hash = {}

inventories.forEach(function(elem) {
  var selected =  Object.assign({}, elem);
  delete selected.name;
  const key = Object.values(selected).join('-');
  hash[key] = elem;
});
const result = Object.values(hash);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is easier to read, but what if I have more properties/parameters in the array? Is it I will need to list out all the property like `elem.x` `elem.y` `elem.z` etc? Is there a way to get the code to ignore what I want to ignore instead of list out what I want?

Comment: Hi @pizza0502, I have updated my code. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter` method with `Object.values` with `...` rest parameter.

```js
let data = [{"name":"Polo Shirt","size":"XL","price":19.9,"color":"black"},{"name":"Polo Shirt (Stripe)","size":"XL","price":19.9,"color":"black"},{"name":"Polo Shirt (Printed)","size":"XL","price":19.9,"color":"black"},{"name":"Short Sleeve Polo Shirt","size":"L","price":14.9,"color":"blue"},{"name":"Sleeve Polo Shirt","size":"L","price":20.9,"color":"black"},{"name":"Long Sleeve Polo Shirt","size":"L","price":14.9,"color":"blue"},{"name":"Long Sleeve Polo Shirt","size":"L","price":14.9,"color":"blue"},{"name":"Long Sleeve Polo Shirt","size":"L","price":14.9,"color":"blue"}]

const uniq = data.reverse().filter(function({name, ...rest}) {
  const key = Object.values(rest).join('-');
  if(!this[key]) return this[key] = true;
  else return false;
}).reverse()

console.log(uniq)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Map` with `.reduce` and take advantage of the fact that it will overwrite any elements set with the same `key` like so:

```js
const inventories = [{"name":"Polo Shirt","size":"XL","price":19.9,"color":"black"},{"name":"Polo Shirt (Stripe)","size":"XL","price":19.9,"color":"black"},{"name":"Polo Shirt (Printed)","size":"XL","price":19.9,"color":"black"},{"name":"Short Sleeve Polo Shirt","size":"L","price":14.9,"color":"blue"},{"name":"Sleeve Polo Shirt","size":"L","price":20.9,"color":"black"},{"name":"Long Sleeve Polo Shirt","size":"L","price":14.9,"color":"blue"},{"name":"Long Sleeve Polo Shirt","size":"L","price":14.9,"color":"blue"},{"name":"Long Sleeve Polo Shirt","size":"L","price":14.9,"color":"blue"}];

const res = [...inventories.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const {name, ...others} = obj;
  const unq_key = Object.values(others).join('_');
  acc.set(unq_key, obj);
  return acc;
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(res);
```